# Subjunctive or indicative after "je ne suis pas sûr si"

Tags: subjonctif

I've learned that the subjunctive is used to express doubt, as in "Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il ait raison".

My question is whether this changes if "que" is replaced by "si". Is it still "Je ne suis pas sûr s'il ait raison", or should the indicative verb "a" be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Je ne suis pas sûr si***... is not idiomatic, if not ungrammatical. The issue is ***pas sûr*** and ***si*** collide as they both express the uncertainty.

Should you really want to take the risk to start your sentence that way, the mode should be the indicative:

> *Je ne suis pas sûr s'il a raison.*

just like we say:

> *Je ne sais pas vraiment s'il a raison.*

but that will raise eyebrows and comments. I would never use it, just like I would never say the equivalent *je doute s'il a raison*.

While extremely rare, this form is found once in a while in French, e.g.:

> ***On n’est pas sûr si c’est vivant*** tout ce qu’on voit. - *Ode à la Misère*, Victor Hugo

> *Remarque: **on n'est pas sûr si l'animal** de cette coquille **est** un mollusque: il appartient peut-être aux annélides* - *Nouveau dictionnaire d'histoire naturelle appliqué aux arts* -  1804

> *J'ai deux ou trois grands-parents juifs, **je ne suis pas sûr si c'est** deux ou trois.* - *Les camps de la honte*, Anne Grynberg - 2013

Comment: It is simply ungrammatical.